# CouchDB[ran out of disk]: How to add a new disk and still insert to the old DB?

Tags: couchdb, mount, diskspace

My couchDB server has run out o f disk space. I want to mount a new volume. Is it possible to tell couchDB to use this new disk to store the new data which should be inserted to the old database? or I need to define completely a new DB?

Comment: This is the wrong place to ask questions about disks and volumes. This question is not about programming.

Answer (score 0):

You should stop CouchDB, copy the database to a new location in your mount disk and set new parameters via the configuration file.

```
[couchdb]
database_dir = /{mnt-disk}/{database-dir}
```

Then start CouchDB, and make sure to have the right permissions to access the new database location.

Comment: But in this way I cannot access the old DB.

Comment: @Alex you cannot have more than one database dir as far as I know, my idea is that you copy your old db to a new block storage volume that is flexible, and can be increased each time you reach your limit, or when you need to compact (2x the size of your actual db).